# Attempt to use mysqldump results in usage suggestions only

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I attempted the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -p sa -n -d -t --routines --skip-triggers --all-databases > C:\backups\MySQLStoredProc.sql
```

but only received back;

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]  
   OR  mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]  
   OR  mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS] 
   For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

I see no problem with my command. Does anyone see a problem with it? The results of mysqldump --version is

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.9, for Win32 (AMD64)
```

Comment: space between -p and 'sa' is causing your problem, presumably 'sa' is not your password and is some options?

Comment: yes, that was the problem. I removed the space. sa is the password.